# CLOSE : Ubuntu 16.04 other website page "The requested URL / was not found on this server"

Tags: 16.04, server

Here is the issu of this p:

In the "Directory /var/www/" add "AllowOverride All" instead of "AllowOverride None" in etc/apache2/apache2.conf

---

Hello

I'm hosted a new website on Ubuntu with apache2.
The website and those other pages worked normally with wamp et mamp but not with my lamp. I can open and view correctly the index page. But when I click to another page here what appear (I remember that the other page open correctly with wamp and mamp).

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rewrite rules aren't being applied. Try accessing the page with normal URL parameters to test that theory. The actual problem is most likely that Apache isn't recognizing the config files. Because this started on Windows, they have probably been renamed in order to cope with the filesystem. You'll either want to rename them back to `.htaccess` or set the configuration setting in your `httpd.conf` file. Look for the `AccessFileName` configuration line and set it to `AccessFileName htaccess.conf` or whatever your site uses.